# How to execute SQL scripts in alphabetical order using a batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

Is it possible to execute all SQL scripts in a folder in alphabetical order using a  batch file ?

Currently I uses the following code but it executes the scripts in the order in which they are kept instead of executing it in alphabetical order

```
SET Database=<<DatabaseName>>
SET ScriptsPath=<<FolderPath>>
SET ServerName=<<ServerName>>


IF EXIST "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt" del "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"

type NUL > "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"

FOR /R "%ScriptsPath%" %%G IN (*.sql *.up) DO (

sqlcmd -d %Database% -S %ServerName% -i "%%G" -o "%%G.txt"

echo .................................................
 >> "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"

echo Executing: "%%G" >> "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"

echo ...................................>> "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"

copy "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"+"%%G.txt" "%ScriptsPath%output_CCF.txt"
del "%%G.txt"

)
```

Comment: What is "order in which they are kept" vs "alphabetical"?

Comment: Good point.  What happens if you change the order of the files to alphabetical and then run the script?

Comment: Basically I have a list of folders

V6.5,

V6.5.1,

V6.5.2,

V6.5.3,

V6.5.4,

V6.5.5,
V6.6,

But when I run my above batch file in "one" of my client systems, the batch file executes in order V6.5.1,

V6.5.2,

V6.5.3,

V6.5.4,

V6.5.5,

V6.5,

V6.6,
But it it works fine with other machines


Any idea why this is happening? This is why I'm thinking of "alphabetical" order

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `/F` option of the `FOR` command, then you can use another command to generate the set of data to be iterated over.

Use this `FOR` statement and I believe you'll find the result you're looking for.

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%G IN (`dir /ON /B *.sql *.up`) DO  ...
```

This uses the `dir` command to generate the set of files to use.  The `/ON` argument orders the files by name and the `/B` argument provides a bare format (no heading information or summary) of the file names.

For more details on the arguments check the help for either of the commands from the command line `dir /?` and `for /?`

Comment: I tried FOR /F "usebackq" %%G IN (`dir "%ScriptsPath%" /ON /B *.sql *.up`) DO .. but it isn't working!! Also I have a list of folders V6.5, V6.5.1, V6.5.2, V6.5.3, V6.5.4, V6.5.5, V6.6 and each of these have .sql files. The files should be executed the above mentioned folder order

Comment: @VinayakPrabha what is the error when it didn't work? Also did you replace `...` with the block of code you want executed?  Also your question didn't ask about multiple folders, but you could do a similar solution with 1 loop inside of another loop. The outside loop would loop over the directories (`dir /on /ad` will be a directory listing of directories sorted in alphabetical order) and the inside loop would loop over the .sql and .up files.